# How to change the resources overriding order from library in Android Studio/Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have one main module and two library modules, `libA` and `libB`.

In `libA`, `string.xml` has a param with name `param1` is equal `SampleText1` and 
in `libB`, `string.xml` `param1` is equal `SampleText2`.

`libA` and `libB` have been added into the main module as library

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libB')
    compile project(':libA')
}
```

Finally, on the main module `param1` equals `SampleText1`, but I want `param1` to be equal `SampleText2`.
I have changed the library order on `dependencies`, but it doesn't have any effect.
Is there any way to change an resources overriding order?

Comment: How are you referencing the value of the string resources?

Comment: I used it in any layout resourse of module `libA` as   

`android:text="@string/param1"`

Comment: You might have to get the string from Java code using the package name of the library that has the wanted value. Or you could fix the libraries to have unique strings.

Comment: in my situation your suggestion not suitable. Therefore package name generating with using gradle flover dynamic and unique name not desirable actually.

Comment: I didn't say anything about Gradle flavors. Your package name has to be unique anyways, so what is not suitable about that?

Comment: My package names are uniqiue in both libs

Answer (score 1):

> My package names are uniqiue in both libs

Good, then nothing needs overriding, you simply need to reference the resource correctly using this format.

```
@[<package_name>:]<resource_type>/<resource_name>
```

So this

```
@string/param1
```

Becomes this

```
@com.example.lib1:string/param1
```

More details at [Accessing Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response but I want override automatically not manually.

Comment: There is no overriding... You have to reference the correct resource

Comment: Okay, that answers that you can generate unique names for the library with a prefix. My answer says you can write the XML differently. I'm not sure what you are trying to say. A Wang did find a solution... There's an accepted answer

Comment: I have solved this task with changing my flavor name with alphabetic order. In result first letter of root module should be before others flavors name in asc order.  this isn't misunderstanding but it works for me. Thank you for your attention

Comment: Alright. You are welcome to provide that as an answer rather than a comment

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this task with changing my flavor name with alphabetic order. In result first letter of root module should be before others flavors name in asc order. This isn't misunderstanding but it works for me.